# SQLAdapter.Update() Method Not Working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and C# and am having a problem adding/updating data to a SQL Server database table.

I have one database with multiple tables. I need to copy certain pieces of data from one table (a table I can not alter (`MASTER`)) to another table (a table I have added to the database (`HELPER`)).

Here is my code. Everything appears to work correctly (no error messages), but no data is added/updated to the destination (`HELPER`) table.

```
conn.Open();

//Get the data from the SOURCE table
SqlDataAdapter AdapterSM = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT lOwnersCorporationID, sPlanNumber FROM OwnersCorporation", conn);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(AdapterSM);
DataSet dsMASTER = new DataSet();
AdapterSM.Fill(dsMASTER, "OwnersCorporation");

//Get the data from the DESTINATION table
SqlDataAdapter AdapterSH = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT lOwnersCorporationID, sPlanNumber FROM StrataHelper", conn);
SqlCommandBuilder builderSH = new SqlCommandBuilder(AdapterSH);
DataSet dsHELPER = new DataSet();
AdapterSH.Fill(dsHELPER, "StrataHelpera");

DataTable tableMASTER = dsMASTER.Tables["OwnersCorporation"];
DataTable tableHELPER = dsHELPER.Tables["StrataHelpera"];

//Merge the data to the DESTINATION table
tableHELPER.Merge(tableMASTER, true);
tableHELPER.AcceptChanges();
dsHELPER.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

AdapterSH.DeleteCommand = builderSH.GetDeleteCommand();
AdapterSH.UpdateCommand = builderSH.GetUpdateCommand();
AdapterSH.InsertCommand = builderSH.GetInsertCommand();

//Update DESTINATION table with merged changes
AdapterSH.Update(dsHELPER, "StrataHelpera");
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Don't call `AcceptChanges()`.

Comment: Hi Michael, I didn't have that method in there initially but it still didn't work. I only added it because I thought it might make a difference. Either way, the database is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should remove acceptchanges ... but even then all rows in dsHELPER.Tables[0] will habe rowstate == Unchanged so your AdapterSH.Update does nothing ... change the rowstate to Added and the Update call will trigger your Insert statement ...

you might have to change your insert statement to target the correct table ... the statement generated by the builder will probably target the source table which is not what you want I guess

Comment: Why would the Rowstate be unchanged, since I know the merge is affecting/adding multiple rows (at least for the first time - subsequent calls would only serve to update any changes) to the HELPER dataset?

I can set the Rowstate manually by using a For loop, but might seem like overkill in subsequent calls when no rows are actually added during the merge.

Comment: have you checked the rowstates after the merge?

Comment: you should also check the sql statement in AdapterSH.InsertCommand ... I guess it will insert into StrataHelper not into StrataHelpera ...

Comment: Ok so changing the Rowstate to 'SetAdded' for each row has done the trick...but I still don't know why the Rowstate was unchanged to begin with?? Sigh.